# How do you determine the average total of a column in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, average

Consider the following Postgresql database table:

```
 id | book_id | author_id
---------------------------
 1  |    1    |    1
 2  |    2    |    1
 3  |    3    |    2
 4  |    4    |    2
 5  |    5    |    2
 6  |    6    |    3
 7  |    7    |    2
```

In this example, Author 1 has written 2 books, Author 2 has written 4 books, and Author 3 has written 1 book. How would I determine the average number of books written by an author using SQL? In other words, I'm trying to get, "An author has written an average of 2.3 books".

Thus far, attempts with AVG and COUNT have failed me. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select avg(totalbooks) from 
(select count(1) totalbooks from books group by author_id) bookcount
```

I think your example data actually only has 3 books for author id 2, so this would not return 2.3

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3e36e/1

With the 4th book:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/67eac/1

Comment: You don't need a subquery. Look into my answer.

Comment: What a wacky way to create the data in the SQLFiddle! You can use a multi-valued VALUES clause to do it much less painfully; see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9635d/1

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a subquery. The inner query will `count` the books with `GROUP BY author`; the outer query will scan the results of the inner query and `avg` them.

You can use a subquery in the `FROM` clause for this, or you can use a CTE (`WITH` expression).

Answer (score 1):

For an average number of books per author you can do simply:

```
SELECT 1.0*COUNT(DISTINCT book_id)/count(DISTINCT author_id) FROM tbl;
```

For number of books per author:

```
SELECT 1.0*COUNT(DISTINCT book_id)/count(DISTINCT author_id) 
FROM tbl GROUP BY author_id;
```

We need 1.0 factor to make the result not integer.

You can remove DISTINCT depending of result you want (it matters only if one book have many authors).

As Craig Ringer rightly pointed out 2 distincts may be expensive. For test performance I have generated 50 000 rows and I got followng results:

- My query with 2 DISTINCTS: ~70ms
- My query with 1 DISTINCT: ~40ms
- Martin Booth's approach: ~30ms

Then added 1 milion rows and tested again:

- My query with 2 DISTINCTS: ~1520ms
- My query with 1 DISTINCT: ~820ms
- Martin Booth's approach: ~1060ms

Then added another 9 milion rows and tested again:

- My query with 2 DISTINCTS: ~17s
- My query with 1 DISTINCT: ~11s
- Martin Booth's approach: ~19s

So there is no universal solution.

Comment: Interesting approach; it should avoid the HashAggregate node of the subquery approach, but will use the somewhat expensive `count(distinct)` on two independent keys. I'd be interested to see how the two compared in performance on a non-trivial data set.

Comment: @CraigRinger: You are right. I added results of performance test to my answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure which way it'd go, actually. Also, "possibly slower" doesn't mean "wrong". Thanks for trying it out.

Comment: I added some rows and tested again. It seems solution should depend on table size.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT AVG(cnt) FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM t
  GROUP BY author_id
) s
```